# Customize Button mute of video

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this code. This works perfect.

```
<button id="mutebtn2">Mute</button></li>
<script>
mutebtn2 = document.getElementById("mutebtn2");
mutebtn2.addEventListener("click",vidmute2,false);
function vidmute2(){
  if(idle_video.muted){
     idle_video.muted = false;
     mutebtn2.innerHTML = "Mute";
  } else {
     idle_video.muted = true;
     mutebtn2.innerHTML = "Unmute";
  }
}
</script>
```

This code mute the video, works fine.

The question is, I want replace the button for a image like on/off. I tried but the code seems me error.
Any help I'm appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text inside `<button id="mutebtn2">Mute</button>` with the img

```
<button id="mutebtn2"><img src="link-to-image" /></button>
```

and with within your `vidmute2()` function, instead of replacing `innerHTML` with text replace with the img html

```
function vidmute2(){
  if(idle_video.muted){
     idle_video.muted = false;
     mutebtn2.innerHTML = "<img src='link-to-image' />";
  } else {
     idle_video.muted = true;
     mutebtn2.innerHTML = "<img src='link-to-image' />";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `src` of an image programmatically in javascript. See [this](http://plnkr.co/BZDOh4oGzCj1xjcIDF3t) for a working example.